# Does zsh have a similar onchange event like html input field when I am typing?

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh

I am writing a commend tool, which need to query a web API after user type finished and hit enter, but the query will take too much time, so I want to perform the query once user stopped typing for a few time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need a web based shell or write your own shell program that has web hooks.

Here is a web based SSH project example. This could be used to interact with your shell from a webpage:
https://github.com/xypiie/WebShell